# Wordpress "Publishing failed. The response is not a valid JSON" when creating a new page

Tags: wordpress

I am using Wordpress 6.4.2, it is a clean installation and I do nothing strange in my theme. When trying to create a new page I get the error "Publishing failed. The response is not a valid JSON" when I try to use the "Post name" permalink structure.

I tried changing to "Plain" and then I could publish it. But the permalink then became something like mysite.com/p=123. I want it to be mysite.com/page-name.

I read about htaccess file causing it but here is my non edited one:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

**How can I create pages with post name permalink structure to get my pages on the format mysite.com/page-name?**

Answer (score 1):

There is no "Page-Name" property in permalinks. Therefore you must use **post-name** or other properties.

Comment: Post name is causing the error